# Filling a combobox with list of available fonts in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP file with an combobox in it. THe combobox will list all available fonts in system. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Client system or server?

Comment: Uhm, I want get the list from server then display on client

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
<%@page import="java.awt.Font"%>
<%@page import="java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment"%>
<html>
    <body>
    <select>
        <%
         GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts(); // Get the fonts
        for (Font f : fonts) {
          %>
            <option><%=f.getFontName() %></option>
          <% 
        }
        %>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```